# <variable name> not defined

Tags: python

```
def calculate_average(runs,games):
    runs_list = [5, 7, 3, 1, 4]
    num_games = len(runs_list)
    total_runs=0
    for runs in runs_list:
            total_runs += runs
    return total_runs/num_games

print(calculate_average(runs, num_games))
```

This gives me an error saying"runs is not defined".I don't get it.Again I am a newbie.I knew it is a steep learning curve.

Comment: What's not clear about it? From what I see it isn't defined where you call the function.

Comment: Your last line (`print`). There is no `runs` variable in that scope.

Comment: why does your `calculate_average` function take `runs` and `games` as parameters, but then doesn't do anything with the values passed in?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I am learning.I found out my mistake.Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `runs` in that `for` loop, you're creating a new variable specific to that loop that can only be changed or accessed by the loop itself. On the last line, you are executing your function with variables that don't exist or even need to.

Your function has all the information it needs already built in, so you can just take out the parameters from both the definition and the execution.

```
def calculate_average():
    runs_list = [5, 7, 3, 1, 4]
    num_games = len(runs_list)
    total_runs=0
    for runs in runs_list:
        total_runs += runs
    return total_runs/num_games

print(calculate_average())
```

If you wanted to use your function more dynamically and/or for other lists, then try this.

```
runs_list = [5, 7, 3, 1, 4]

def calculate_average(list):
    num_games = len(list)
    total_runs=0
    for runs in list:
        total_runs += runs
    return total_runs/num_games

print(calculate_average(runs_list))
```

Here you define your list outside of the function and use it as a parameter, so you can now sub in any list you want to average.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were aiming for something like this:

```
def calculate_average(runs_list):
    num_games = len(runs_list)
    total_runs = 0
    for runs in runs_list:
        total_runs += runs
    return total_runs / num_games

print(calculate_average([5, 7, 3, 1, 4]))
```

Comment: Yes. I fixed it. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve.